# Collatz conjecture returns decimals instead of integer (python)

Tags: python, collatz

Complete rookie. When I run the below it returns decimals. How do I get this to return whole number?

```
n = 17

while n != 1:         
    if (n % 2 == 0):  
        n = n/2          
        print(int(n))
    else:             
        n = (3*n)+1
        print(int(n))
```

Result:

```
py> python cold.py
52
26.0
13.0
40.0
20.0
10.0
5.0
16.0
8.0
4.0
2.0
1.0
```

Comment: Even with the calls to `int` it still returns decimals?

Comment: In case you don't want to look at the duplicate, in Python 3, int/int returns a float, int//int does integer division.